# How can I combine two fields in a SelectList text description?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I want put in a selected list labels the name and surname of people of an EF model.
I've tried with this:

```
public ActionResult Insert()
        {
            ViewData["accountlist"] = new SelectList(time.Anagrafica_Dipendente.ToList(), "ID_Dipendente", "Surname Name", null);             
            Giustificativi g = new Giustificativi();
            return View(g);
        }
```

but VS returns an error, because there isn't a attribute called "surname name".
how can i concat the name and surname in the selectlist label?

thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
ViewData["accountlist"] = 
    new SelectList((from s in time.Anagrafica_Dipendente.ToList() select new { 
        ID_Dipendente=s.ID_Dipendente,
        FullName = s.Surname + " " + s.Name}), 
        "ID_Dipendente", 
        "FullName", 
        null);
```

Comment: This technique also allows combining properties from different linked objects. eg `FullName = s.Parent.Surname + s.Name`

Answer (score 36):

Add a new property to `time.Anagrafica_Dipendente` which will represent the concatenation of the two properties:

```
public string Fullname 
{
    get 
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Surname, Name);
    }
}
```

and then use this:

```
ViewData["accountlist"] = new SelectList(
    time.Anagrafica_Dipendente.ToList(), 
    "ID_Dipendente", 
    "Fullname", 
    null
);
```

---

Update: As of C# 6.0, the property can be more concisely written as:

```
public string Fullname => string.Format("{0} {1}", Surname, Name);
```

Learn more about expression-bodied properties [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/03/c-sharp-6-expression-bodied-properties-dictionary-initializer.aspx).

Comment: In order for that to work, `Fullname` would have to be a member of `time.Anagrafica_Dipendente`.

Comment: i can't believe i couldn't think of that my self, simple and elegant, love it!

Comment: Or even more succinctly using `public string Fullname => $"{Surname} {Name}";`

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this answer and my easy way is adding a NotMapped attribute, this is my code:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName
   {
     get
       {
         return Name + " " + LastName;
       }
   }
```

Then you can use the normal way in the controller, this is my code, Owner the the foreign key related to `AspNetUsers`

```
ViewBag.Owner = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "FullName", product.Owner);
```

Answer (score 2):

On view

```
<select asp-for="AccountId" 
            asp-items='new SelectList(from x in Accounts select new { Value = x.AccountId ,Text = x.Name + " " + x.Surname}, "Value","Text")'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .Net 6 Core, but pretty sure I've been doing this for a while now. I broke it into two pieces, but you can cram it all into one `SelectList`:

```
var accountList = time.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Select(x => new 
{
  x.ID_Dipendente,
  FullName = x.Surname + " " + x.Name
});

var selectList = new SelectList(accountList, "ID_Dipendente", "FullName");
```