# ASP MVC SelectList() Name Concatenation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which works:

```
ViewBag.Resources = New SelectList(db1.Tbl_Resources, "Resource_ID", "Resource_FirstName")
```

I want to not only show the first name, but also the last name so I tried this:

```
ViewBag.Resources = New SelectList(db1.Tbl_Resources, "Resource_ID", "Resource_FirstName" + " " + "Resource_LastName")
```

However, it didn't work because it seems to look for a model property called "`Resource_FirstNameResource_LastName`."  How can I concatenate these for use in the SelectList() method?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that before I posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the SelectList constructor in Mvc uses the dataTextField argument and reflection to "pull" the property value at runtime, there's no way to accomplish what you are doing there HOWEVER, a simple workaround

Create a new readonly properly on your table class (use partial class if using EF) called "Caption" for example. Then in the getter return Resource_FirstName" + " " + Resource_LastName

```
class db1.Tbl_Resources
{
    public string Caption { get {return Resource_FirstName + " " + Resource_LastName;}}
}
```

Then in your View or Helper

```
New SelectList(db1.Tbl_Resources, "Resource_ID", "Caption");
```

At least that's how I handle that scenario, which is fairly common.

Comment: Cool answer.  Thanks for your help.  I will accept this as the solution.  Note:  In order to convert to VB, I had to remove the `db1.` from the class header.

Comment: I wanted to also say the dataTextField name must match exactly a property name on the class so reflection works. Hope it helps you.