# Multiple Values in SelectList text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to show multiple values in `dropdownlist` text. The example is given following.

```
SelectList(Parts, "pno", "pcode"+"pname")
```

where

`pno` is Part number.

`pcode` is part code.

`pname` is part name

Now please tell me how can i concatenate part code and name with out using viewmodel(I want to do it using domain model).

Comment: can you show the query for the list?

Comment: Parts.Where(p => p.PartID == partid.Value);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to microsoft documentation, SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String) Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, and the data text field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

In order to do this, you would want to concatenate the name into a new property on your model.  The below stack overflow answer with 8 ups is my favorite way to do this.

[How can I combine two fields in a SelectList text description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description)

In your case, it would look something like this...

```
public class Model
{
    public string pcode { get; set; }
    public string pname { get; set; }
    public string ConcatDescription { get; set; }

    public string ConcatDescription 
    {
        get 
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", pcode , pname );
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just call that property directly.

```
SelectList(Parts, "pno", "ConcatDescription ")
```

EDIT:  Added in code for clarification.

Comment: @Zeb-ur-Rehman this would come from your domain model.  I wasn't sure the name of it.  The code example I provided above is my interpretation of your domain model

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether this will help. In a c# point of view, you can structure your class like

```
public class Parts
{
    public string PartCode { get; set; }

    public string PartName { get; set; }

    public string PartNo
    {
        get
        {
            return PartCode + PartName;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

and then use the select list like.

```
SelectList(Parts, "PartNo")
```