# Combine 2 fields in SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Currently I have SelectList that writes ID, and shows FirstName on the form.

```
ViewBag.Person = new SelectList(db.Person, "ID", "FirstName");
```

How to concatenate FirstName and LastName into SelectList? Something like:

```
ViewBag.Person = new SelectList(db.Person, "ID", "FirstName & LastName");
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ViewBag.Person = 
new SelectList((from s in db.Person select new { 
    ID=s.ID,
    FullName = s.FirstName+ " " + s.LastName}), 
    "ID", 
    "FullName", 
    null);
```

Or Add a new property to your Person model

```
public string Fullname 
{
    get 
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  I would definitely recommend adding it to the model as shown in the second example above.  This way you can reuse the "Fullname" property from other parts of your application.