# MVC5: Posting JSON via Ajax not correctly passing data to Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to do some duplication checking in my MVC5/EF Code-First application. On my `Create()` Asset View, I show/hide textboxes for entering a new `location_dept`/`location_room` via JS:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location_Id, "Location_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Location:</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("Location_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Model_List, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectLocation" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="createNewLocation" type="button" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">CREATE NEW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="createLocationFormContainer" style="display:none">
                <form action="/createNewLocation">
                    <input type="text" id="textNewLocationDept" name="location_dept" placeholder="New Department" />
                    <input type="button" id="submitNewLocation" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancelNewLocation" value="Cancel" /><br />
                    <input type="text" id="textNewLocationRoom" name="location_room" placeholder="New Room" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#createNewLocation').click(function () {
            $('#createLocationFormContainer').show();
        })

        $('#cancelNewLocation').click(function () {
            $('#createLocationFormContainer').hide();
        })

        $('#submitNewLocation').click(function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = { location_dept: document.getElementById('textNewLocationDept').value, location_room: document.getElementById('textNewLocationRoom').value };
            // CORRECTLY SHOWING
            alert("Dept: " + data.location_dept + " | Room: " + data.location_room);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewLocation", "INV_Assets")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.LocationRoomExists)
                    {
                        alert("Room Location [" + resp.Text + "] already exists. Please select from the DropDown.");
                    } else {
                        // FALSE
                        alert("LocationRoomExists: " + resp.LocationRoomExists);
                        // `undefined` returned for both values
                        alert("Department: " + resp.location_dept + " | Room: " + resp.location_room);
                        $ $('#selectLocation').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.LocDept + "| " + resp.LocRoom));
                        $('#createLocationFormContainer').hide();
                        var count = $('#selectLocation option').size();
                        $("#selectLocation").prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR - Something went wrong adding new Room Location [" + resp.Text + "]!");
                    $('#createLocationFormContainer').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

I then use a JSON `POST` to my controller action to create the new `INV_Location`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult createNewLocation(string department, string room)
    {
        INV_Locations location = new INV_Locations()
        {
            // ID auto-set during save.
            location_dept = department,
            location_room = room,
            created_date = DateTime.Now,
            created_by = System.Environment.UserName
        };

        var duplicateLocation = db.INV_Locations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.location_room.ToUpper() == location.location_room.ToUpper());

        try
        {
            if (duplicateLocation == null)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.INV_Locations.Add(location);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                location = duplicateLocation;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        return Json(new { ID = location.Id, LocDept = location.location_dept, LocRoom = location.location_room, LocationRoomExists = (duplicateLocation != null) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I run the code all together, I get a result in my dropdown of `undefined|undefined`. After some debugging I determined that my controller is not receiving a `department`/`room` value (`null`).

Can anyone spot what might be going wrong with my AJAX call to my controller?

**EDIT**:

`$('#selectLocation').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.LocDept + "| " + resp.LocRoom));`

Comment: Looks like your form is actually submitting rather than accessing the controller via AJAX. Research preventing default events. If it *is* submitting via AJAX, try changing the variable names in your `data` object to match the parameters in the action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your parameters match that you are sending:

```
var data = { department: document.getElementById('textNewLocationDept').value, room: document.getElementById('textNewLocationRoom').value };
```

You also need to match the data that you are returning from your controller.

Your action returns this:

```
new { ID = location.Id, LocDept = location.location_dept, 
      LocRoom = location.location_room, 
      LocationRoomExists = (duplicateLocation != null) }
```

So your bind needs to match the properties i.e.

```
$('#selectLocation').append($('<option></option>')
   .val(resp.Id).text(resp.LocRoom   + "| " + resp.LocDept ));
```

Comment: Thanks hutchonoid, I had just caught that myself. Unfortunately not the root of the issue. When I enter in `Dept: IT | Room: Storage` (A value which DOES already exist in the database, my Controller code does not flag a duplication and goes all the way down to `db.SaveChanges()` where an `Exception` then catches: `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic see the first update too, i.e. data parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That was it (seems I've run into that issue before but overlooked it this time). I know it's a slightly unrelated note, but would you have any idea of how to show the `Dept|Room` in my DropDownList when the View Loads? The 2 fields are in my `INV_Locations` table, and currently I just pass the `Room` to the list via the `ViewBag`: `ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_room");`.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Hi Sorry, just seen your above comment. Try this `ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList() { new { Id = l.Id, dep_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room}}, "Id", "dep_room");` :)

Comment: Your example is flagging every use of `l` as not existing in current context, and the last 2 parameters simply come up as `; expected`. Are you meaning this to be in the Controller or on the View? My Controller for `Location` is currently the following: `ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_room", iNV_Assets.Location_Id);`

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Sorry, I didn't have a test project setup to test it. This looks like it will be the same here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description

Comment: Thanks, that got me close. I had to open a new question though due to a small issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169132/combine-2-entity-framework-model-fields-in-1-selectlist