# Combine 2 Entity Framework Model fields in 1 SelectList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, viewdata

I am attempting to display 2 fields from my `INV_Locations` Model within a SelectList: `location_dept|location_room` or for example `IT|Storage`. Using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description) post I pieced the below together via `ViewData`:

**INV_AssetsController - Edit() GET**:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        INV_Assets iNV_Assets = await db.INV_Assets.FindAsync(id);
        if (iNV_Assets == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.History = GetHistoryByAssetId(id);

        ViewData["Location_Id"] = new SelectList((from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList() select new { location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }), "location_room", null, null);
    }
```

**INV_AssetsController - Edit() HttpPost**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Model_Id,Manufacturer_Id,Type_Id,Location_Id,Vendor_Id,Status_Id,ip_address,mac_address,note,owner,cost,po_number,description,invoice_number,serial_number,asset_tag_number,acquired_date,disposed_date,created_date,created_by,modified_date,modified_by")] INV_Assets iNV_Assets)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            iNV_Assets.modified_date = DateTime.Now;
            iNV_Assets.modified_by = System.Environment.UserName;
            db.Entry(iNV_Assets).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ViewData["Location_List"] = new SelectList((from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList() select new { location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }), "location_room", null, null);
        return View(iNV_Assets);
    }
```

**INV_Assets - Edit() View**:

```
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Location:</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("Location_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location_Id, (SelectList)ViewData["Location_List"], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectLocation" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

This is close, rendering (ex.) the following in my dropdown:

`{ location_room = IT|Server }`, `{ location_room = IT|Storage }`, etc.

Does anyone know the syntax change I need to make in order to only display the relevant part in the selectlist (`IT|Server`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the `dataTextField` property in the `SelectList` constructor so it defaults to the `ToString()` method of the anonymous object. It needs to be: (note the last parameter is not required)

```
ViewData["Location_List"] = new SelectList((from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList()
  select new { location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }),
  "location_room", "location_room");
```

Side notes:

1. Your GET method has `ViewData["Location_Id"]` (I assume this is a
   typo and it should be `ViewData["Location_List"]` (as per the POST
   method)
2. You have not shown your model but `Location_Id` would suggest an
   identifier property (usually `int`) so I am not sure how you would
   expect this to work. You are binding the text value "IT|Server" or
   "IT|Storage" to the property `Location_Id` which I suspect has no
   relationship to your model or the database fields. I suspect what
   you really need here is cascading dropdown lists, one for the
   department, and the second for the room (bound to `Location_Id`
   which is updated using ajax when a department is selected.
3. I suggest you re-factor generating the `SelectList` (and other
   common code) to a private method to avoid duplicating code.
4. I strongly recommend you learn to use view models and stop mixing up
   models `ViewBag` and `ViewData` and remove that dreadful
   `[Bind(Include = "..")]` attribute

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I think I may be running into an issue related to this on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212337/cannot-create-edit-record-due-to-validation . I had attempted 2 dropdowns in the past, but it did not like me using the same model to fill 2 different select lists based upon 2 different fields (and I don't want to create seperate Tables/Models just for 2 fields?) -- It's all functioning now other than the validation flagging on the dropdown despite a "valid" selection having been made.

Comment: I see you have accepted an answer on the other question (which really relates to note 2 above) so assumes it OK now. But I still consider what you doing is an awful hack that will give you future problems. There is no reason why cascading drop downs wont work.

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
    var ReportingManager = _context.EmployeeDetailMaster.Select(s => new {
                        RecID = s.RecId,
                        ReportingManagerName = s.FirstName + " " + s.MiddleName + " " + s.LastName
                    });

ViewData.ReportingManager = new SelectList(ReportingManager, "RecId", "ReportingManagerName");
```