# Cannot Create()/Edit() record due to Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My Inventory Tracking program has a main class called `INV_Assets`. This includes `[ForeignKey]` fields for several child tables including `INV_Locations`:

```
    [Required]
    public int Location_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
    public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }
```

Now then, on my `Create()/Edit()` action methods for `INV_Assets` I am filling a `ViewData[]` element with a `SelectList` to be used on the View (this Select List combines 2 of my `INV_Locations` fields into one within the dropdown - ex. [location_dept]|[location_room] - [IT]|[Server]):

```
ViewData["Location_Id"] = new SelectList((from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList() select new { location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }), "location_room", "location_room");
```

Then on my View I used the `ViewData[]` element to fill a `SelectList/DropDownListFor`:

```
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Location:</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location_Id, (SelectList)ViewData["Location_List"], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectLocation" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

My DropDownList is correctly being filled as I intend, but after I make a Selection (be it changing the selection `[IT]|[Server] => [IT]|[Cubicle]` for Edit() or `[<<< SELECT >>>] => [IT]|[Server]` for Create()) once focus shifts away I get the Validation/Error message `"The field Location_Id must be a number."`

Can someone with more experience weigh in with what I need to modify to keep this validation in place, but to be properly implemented? I may be combining the fields [location_dept]|[location_room] visually in the DropDown, but the `Id` for the `INV_Location` should be the same?

If it helps below is my `INV_Locations` Model:

```
public class INV_Locations
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.location_dept + "|" + this.location_room;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Location Dept.")]
    public string location_dept { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Room.")]
    public string location_room { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string created_by { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

    public string modified_by { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are population your dropdown for `Location_Id` with strings

```
select new { location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }
```

And your model expects it to be an int.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but how do I show the [Dept]|[Room] and still have the validation in place to ensure a selection is made? Each unqiue ID is shown in the dropdown with the Concatenation of [location_dept]|[location_room].

Comment: What you display doesn't have to be the same as what you select. Try something like this `ViewData["Location_Id"] = new SelectList((from l in db.INV_Locations.ToList() select new { location_id = <locationIdField>, location_room = l.location_dept + "|" + l.location_room }), "location_id", "location_room");'

Comment: Let me do some testing, I think that may have done the trick.