# ASP.NET Dropdown Menu from List issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am populating a dropdown menu like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.timeSlot, new SelectList(ViewBag.TimeSlots, "id", "timeSlot"), "")
```

which comes from here:

```
private CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots dbTimeSlots = new CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots();

ViewBag.TimeSlots = dbTimeSlots.Data.ToList();
```

which comes from here:

```
public class CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Time Slots")]
        public string timeSlot { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date Slots")]
        public string dateSlot { get; set; }
    }

    public class CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I am looking to adjust this dropdown menu so it has both timeSlot and dateSlot like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.timeSlot, new SelectList(ViewBag.TimeSlots, "id", "dateSlot timeSlot"), "")
```

but I get this error:

```
does not contain a property with the name 'dateSlot timeSlot'.
```

Can I have both in 1 dropdown? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758734/how-can-i-combine-two-fields-in-a-selectlist-text-description

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your source a bit, as SelectList expects a name of a single field. But you can easily have this with LINQ's Select:

```
ViewBag.TimeSlots.Select(ts => new {
    Id = ts.id,
    Text = ts.dateSlot + " " + ts.timeSlot
})
```

And this is what you give to SelectList. Make sure that you provide names of new properties now, and also cast your list to concrete type:

```
new SelectList(
    ((IEnumerable<TimeSlot>)ViewBag.TimeSlots).Select(ts => new {
    Id = ts.id,
    Text = ts.dateSlot + " " + ts.timeSlot
}),
"Id", "Text")
```

Comment: I get this error with the first part: `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`

Comment: @user979331 That is probably because of dynamic nature of viewbag. Edited, although I had to guess the type of time slot object, but you can figure it out

Comment: This is still giving me the same error: `ViewBag.TimeSlots.Select(ts => new {
    Id = ts.id,
    Text = ts.dateSlot + " " + ts.timeSlot
})`

Comment: @user979331, you do not see to use the casting operation i added to the post