# ASP.NET add items to List from Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this class here:

```
public class CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Time Slots")]
        public string timeSlot { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date Slots")]
        public string dateSlot { get; set; }
    }

    public class CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Now what I am trying to do is put each item of the class into a List, I have created this list:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
```

What I am looking to add to this list is a the id and timeSlot and DateSlot, however I want the timeSlot and DateSlot as a combined string. So my new list will have id and some string called timeDateSlot...I hope this make sense, how would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have at least code that adds the one field to the list?

Comment: You're not going to be able to put two distinct values (i.e., `id` and a concatenated `itemSlot` + `dateSlot` into a `List<string>`.  You'll need a `List<T>` where T is the class with the `id` field and the `timeDateSlot` field.

Comment: you could just add the class items themselves to a list via  'List<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots> newList = new List<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots>();' then do a foreach for each item in the DB

Comment: @AlexRohr can I see an example of the foreach?

Comment: @user979331 let me just write an answer instead :)

Comment: Voted to close. Seems like you're here for a copy/paste answer judging by your comments on other answers...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots` called `test`:

```
newList.add(test.id.ToString());
newList.add(test.timeSlot + test.dateSlot);
```

However, you do not get to choose identifiers for these string.

Comment: Will this add all items to the list?

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Sounds hacky.

Comment: @user979331 What do you mean 'all items'? If by all 3 items on the object, then yes. You will have two strings. One will be the id, and the other will be the timeSlot and dateSlot concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to store a list of your TimeSlots class then what you need is a list of `KeyValuePair`s.

`List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`

and in this you can add:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(test.id.ToString(), test.timeSlot + test.dateSlot));
```

Comment: wow...i figured you would know how to iterate each item and add it. thiscode wasn't meant for copy/paste - advise you to stop "coding" and pick up a book to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots> newList = new List<CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots>();
foreach(var x in CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots){ //whatever your db data is
    newList.add(x);             //add an instance to list
}
```

Something like this might help. Then you could display like so,

```
var x = newList.first();
string combined = x.timeSlot + x.dateSlot;
```

Comment: I get error with this line `foreach(var x in CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots)` is a type but used a variable

Comment: @user979331 fill the CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots with where ever you are gathering the data from (I am unsure where you are collecting the stuff for the list)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify data using Id you can use the following code

```
foreach(CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots d in CPVIPPreviewTimeSlots.Data)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> lstIdWiseData = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
    lstIdWiseData.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(d.Id, string.Concat(d.timeSlot, d.dateSlot )));
}
```

If your id is not unique you can replace `KeyValuePair<int,string>` with `Tuple<int,string>` in the above code

Comment: @user979331 d in the above code is object of class "CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots"

Comment: @user979331 Perhaps the edit in answer will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra property to your class to get the correct string that is accessible anywhere:

```
    public class CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Time Slots")]
        public string timeSlot { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date Slots")]
        public string dateSlot { get; set; }

        public string combinedString
        {
            get
            {
                return timeSlot + " " + dateSlot;
            }
        }
    }
```

This can then also be used in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160439/asp-net-dropdown-menu-from-list-issue)

```
        DropDownList1.DataSource = newList;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "combinedString";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "timeSlot";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```