# ASP.NET Add items to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add items to a list:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
foreach (var x in dbTimeSlots.Data)
{
    newList.Add(x.id.ToString());
    newList.Add(x.timeSlot + " - " + x.dateSlot);
}
```

However my list returns 80 items when I only have 40, this is happening because the id will be one item and the the time and date will be another, I need them as one row, but each row should have an id object, and date and time object. I hope this makes sense, please help!!!!

Comment: Create a model to store the type you want or use an anonymous type.

Comment: use the debugger.. you have 2 calls to the `.Add()` method.. what are you truly trying to do.. perhaps you should create a Class and then populate the class and have a List<Class>

Comment: Seems to be a follow-on to the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40161437/745969)....and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40161542/745969).  @Gavin explained you would get two strings for each object in his comment.

Answer (score 7):

> I need them as one row, but each row should have an id object, and
>   date and time object

Then you don't need a `List<string>` but a `List<CustomObject>` where `CustomObject` is an object with the properties you specified. Then for each item in `dbTimeSlots.Data` you should create such an object and then add this to your list.

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
    public string DateSlot { get; set; }
}
```

Then with the `foreach` loop:

```
var newList = new List<CustomObject>();
foreach (var x in dbTimeSlots.Data)
{
    var customObject = new CustomObject
    {
        Id = x.id.ToString(),
        TimeSlot = x.timeSlot,
        DateSlot = x.dateSlot
    };
    newList.Add(customObject);
}
```

Or with `LINQ`:

```
var newList = dbTimeSlots.Data.Select(x => new CustomObject
{
    Id = x.id.ToString(),
    TimeSlot = x.timeSlot,
    DateSlot = x.dateSlot
}).ToList();
```

Comment: example code please, I am exhausted and just want to get this working so I can go home.

Comment: the above example is pretty straight forward. @user979331 what did you not understand ?

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh The example code was added *after* the OP asked for it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model to store the type you want or use an anonymous type.

```
var newList = dbTimeSlots.Data.Select(x => new 
    { 
         id = x.id, 
         timeDateSlot = x.timeSlot + " - " + x.dateSlot 
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option that may work for you is to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`.

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var x in dbTimeSlots.Data)
{
    myDictionary.Add(x.id.ToString(), x.timeSlot + " - " + x.dateSlot);
}
```